# how do i loop through folders alphabetically up to certain folders

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell so please pardon me with my pseudocode below. Is there any in-built method in shell that could help me iterate up to certain folders i..e `[A-M0-9]`

first i want to cd into the parent directory that consists of folders name starting from `A-Z`then once i am in the parent folder i want to sort the parent directory alphabetically and then iterate through sub-directories from [A-M0-9].

Below would the pseudocode of something what i am trying to attempt -

```
cd /temp/parentDir

for f in [A-M0-9]
do
echo $f
done
```

Comment: What is [A-MO-9] if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: It's a regex that will match any character between A and M or between 0 and 9. So it won't match N-Z or a-z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually really close. All you need is a wildcard:

```
for f in [A-M0-9]*; do
    echo $f
done
```

Comment: Awesome i didn't know i was that close. I just tried what u suggested and it worked. Thank you very much !

Comment: You may want to use `shopt -s nullglob` to be more robust.